# How to merge sequenced duplicate values inside string_agg

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like the following:

```
create table path(
  id integer,
  start varchar(255),
  finish varchar(255),
  client integer

);

INSERT INTO path(id, start, finish, client) VALUES (1, '1', '2', 1);
INSERT INTO path(id, start, finish, client) VALUES (2, '2', '3', 1);
INSERT INTO path(id, start, finish, client) VALUES (3, '3', '4', 1);
INSERT INTO path(id, start, finish, client) VALUES (4, '5', '6', 1);
```

I've tried the following query:

```
select string_agg(start || ' -> ' ||finish, ', ' order by id) from path group by client;
```

and the result was like that:

```
1 -> 2, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6
```

How can I get the following result if two sequenced values are the same:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6
```

Here's the [Sql Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/af5be/1).

Comment: Instead of `String_Agg()` you will need to do a [Recursive CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm sorry, but I think it's not giving me what I need. I've edited my question since I think that it was a bit unclear.

Comment: The solution is still a recursive cte. You just need to tweak to get your answer. I will try to update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, a recursive CTE will produce this. [As an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/af5be/5):

```
WITH RECURSIVE reccte AS
(
  /*Recursive Seed - Records that will start recursion*/
  SELECT id, start, finish, client, start || '->' || finish as path, 1 as depth
  FROM path
  WHERE id = 1
  UNION ALL
  /*Recursive Term - This will be the statement that iterates until the join fails*/
  SELECT
    path.id, path.start, path.finish, path.client, reccte.path || '->' || path.finish, depth + 1
  FROM reccte 
    INNER JOIN path ON reccte.finish = path.start
  WHERE depth < 20 /*make sure we don't loop endlessly*/
)
SELECT * FROM reccte;


+----+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+
| id | start | finish | client |     path      | depth |
+----+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+
|  1 |     1 |      2 |      1 | 1->2          |     1 |
|  2 |     2 |      3 |      1 | 1->2->3       |     2 |
|  3 |     3 |      4 |      1 | 1->2->3->4    |     3 |
|  4 |     4 |      5 |      1 | 1->2->3->4->5 |     4 |
+----+-------+--------+--------+---------------+-------+
```

That final `SELECT` can be changed out to `SELECT path FROM reccte ORDER BY depth DESC LIMIT 1;` in this example to go after the record you want.

UPDATED:

The solution is still the same here, we just tweak the recursive CTE and final select to get the different full branches/path for your hierarchy:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2892f/6

```
WITH RECURSIVE reccte AS
(
  SELECT id as origin, id, start, finish, client, start || ' -> ' || finish as path, 1 as depth
  FROM path
  WHERE start NOT IN (SELECT distinct finish FROM path)
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    reccte.origin, path.id, path.start, path.finish, path.client, reccte.path || ' -> ' || path.finish, depth + 1
  FROM reccte 
    INNER JOIN path ON reccte.finish = path.start
  WHERE depth < 20 /*make sure we don't loop endlessly*/
)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT origin, path, depth, max(depth) OVER (PARTITION BY origin) as maxdepth FROM reccte) sub WHERE sub.maxdepth = depth;


+--------+------------------+-------+----------+
| origin |       path       | depth | maxdepth |
+--------+------------------+-------+----------+
|      1 | 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 |     3 |        3 |
|      4 | 5 -> 6           |     1 |        1 |
+--------+------------------+-------+----------+
```

You can string_agg() here too in that final select to get EXACTLY the output in your updated question:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/2892f/5

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(path, ', ' order by origin) FROM (SELECT origin, path, depth, max(depth) OVER (PARTITION BY origin) as maxdepth FROM reccte) sub WHERE sub.maxdepth = depth;

+--------------------------+
|        string_agg        |
+--------------------------+
| 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4, 5 -> 6 |
+--------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate your help :)